# Alternative of Sparse LInear Method (SLIM) package

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

please I develop my code on google Colab, and I want to use the Sparse LInear Method (SLIM) package

https://github.com/KarypisLab/SLIM

But it doesn't support pip installation !!!
Is there an alternative to this package to install on google Colab?
and thank you

Comment: You have asked your question in the wrong place. The `slim` tag you used is for the PHP micro-framework [Slim](https://www.slimframework.com/)

Comment: no it's not a PHP framework !! https://github.com/KarypisLab/SLIM

Comment: I know that you are not interested in the Slim PHP framework but the tag you use with your question is for that framework not for Sparse LInear Method.

Comment: so what can I write as tag?